# Initial value of these pointers in Monetdb

Tags: pointers, monetdb

While coming across Monetdb source there are three structures which were used most often. They are

MalBlkPtr mb
MalStkPtr stk
InstrPtr pci

What are they meant for? What is their initial value and when do they get initialized?

Answer (score 0):

See the source code mal.h.
MAL block pointer, MAL stack pointer, and Instruction pointer.
They are initialized while parsing a MAL program of instruction.